# Are users aware of Super Mario Maker mechanics, and would puzzle courses be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are users on this site aware of the various mechanics in the game Super Mario Maker, and would posting self-made (or found) puzzles on here be regarded as on topic?

For an example of a puzzle level, check out https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7pLg5Rn1BwU

*Note: I am not the creator of the video, nor am I advertising for this guy. Simply providing a relevant example to my question*

Answer (score 8):

My take on this would be that a puzzle that requires the viewer to actually own the video game to solve would be out of place. That sort of thing would best be posted on some internet community of people owning the game, say the mario maker reddit, etc. Those without the game on this community couldn't enjoy the puzzle, and if such puzzles become popular, it would basically degrade the quality of this site for them.

That being said, a puzzle that uses the mechanics of Super Mario that can be described in terms of images or text could be fun. Ideally, the first such puzzle could quickly describe the relevant mechanics needed to understand the puzzle.

Comment: Yeah, cause such a puzzle could instead become a form of "picture puzzle" and can exist independently of mario-related content. At least, in the sense that it could represent a broad genre of which mario maker levels may be a subset.

Answer (score 5):

**Note**: I think you can safely expand your question to include *all* "interactive" puzzles (in fact you can probably go even broader, to include any puzzles requiring content hosted/contained elsewhere)

---

As cool as I think interactive puzzles would be, I believe they fall outside the scope of Puzzling (and StackExchange as a whole too).

The current consensus, for StackExchange sites generally, is that posts questions/answers should be as self-contained as possible. For example, it's frowned upon on StackOverflow to provide a link as an answer, and posters should instead summarise the content.

The reasoning:

- It protects against link rot, where a post can become completely valueless if the thing it links to (or requires, in the case of a game) becomes inaccessible or obsolete for whatever reason
- It assists the goals of SE, in becoming a public *repository* of information, rather than an *index*

Another issue specific to interactive puzzles like mario maker, is: How do solvers post answers? By taking screenshots and drawing lines everywhere? Capturing a video and linking to youtube?

As I said, a nice idea, but just seems like an awkward (at best) fit for PSE...

Comment: I've seen people ask for game related puzzle stuff before. Also I was thinking something along the lines of instructions :P